# Not getting where data with filter (elastic search 6.4)

Tags: elasticsearch

**elasticsearch version: 6.4**

Here is my current data:

[image]

I want to search for products which has Xbox in name. I am using the match keyword but that is not working.

Below is my elastic search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "xbox"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "deep_sub": [
                            "Konsol Oyunları",
                            "Konsol Aksesuarları"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face such kind of issues, try breaking down the query. You have [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). Run both of them individually and see what's not working.

From what I understand, looks like your field deep_sub is of `text` type and this would mean Term Query is not returning results.

You would need to create its sibling equivalent using [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type *and then* run Term Query on it for exact matches.

From the above link we have the below info:

> Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value.

If you do not control the mapping, meaning if your mapping if of dynamic type, then you must have its sibling equivalent keyword field available which would be `deep_sub.keyword`

You can check by running `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping`

Your query would then be as follows:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "name":{  
                     "query":"xbox"
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "deep_sub.keyword":[         <----- Change This
                     "Konsol Oyunları",
                     "Konsol Aksesuarları"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":50
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Was the above useful? Did it solve what you were looking for? Let me know if you are looking for anything else.